# Cross-domain policy and XHR cookie for app development in Safari, Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise, session-cookies, httponly

I'm developing a web services application using various technologies such as :

Ruby on Rails on server side
Javascript, HTML5, objective-C, java on mobile side

I did not met any issue with developing the application until I updated my safari browser. I actually run :

**Version 5.1.1 (7534.51.22)**

I'm developing the mobile application using the [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) Framework. It works great when the js applicatin is wrapped by phonegap, but now, when I'm developing in safari with the protocole file://, my cookie are not saved.

Before I updated my safari version, the cookie was saved and correctly send to the server each time I made request.

To reproduce :

A. Opening the index.html file in a safari window :

file://~/project/myapp/index.html

B.XHR to the server with http: //localhost:3000/sign_in

C. You get the cookie and the correct success code from the server

D. You try to fetch other information using

http: //localhost:3000/users/1

you get : **401 Unauthorized**.

Well, the server has not changed, only safari has been updated. What would be the correct way to do it.
And of course it works when I built the app for iOS, blackberry or Android.

Thank you !